# CMake'ifying a Boost Jam project: check-target-builds

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace, bjam, b2

I'm trying to "De-boostify" one of the Boost libraries, which is more or less stand-alone anyway <sup>*</sup>.

Now, Boost uses its own Build System, [B2](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/master/index.html), which uses "Jam files" for configuration; so I'm trying to migrate this library's Jam file into a `CMakeLists.txt`.

A construct I'm having trouble with is the `check-target-builds` command, used in the [Jam file](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/blob/develop/build/Jamfile.v2) of the library I'm converting. I understand what its different operands mean, but what I don't understand is: How does B2 know how to configure the build of the first argument to `check-target-builds`? I mean, those targets are not defined anywhere. Is there some kind of default where B2 will look for a `.cpp` of the same name as the missing target? Or is it more complicated than that?

---

<sub>It is Antony Polukhin's wonderful [`stacktrace` library](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace); which gives you easy access to stacktraces, with names and line numbers and no hassle. My de-boostification efforts so far can be found [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/stacktrace/).</sub>

Comment: have you considered vcpkg? It has the stacktrace library as a separate module. It does depend on some other boost modules, but nothing heavy: `Build-Depends: boost-array, boost-build, boost-config, boost-container-hash, boost-core, boost-modular-build-helper, boost-predef, boost-static-assert, boost-type-traits, boost-vcpkg-helpers, boost-winapi` https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/boost-stacktrace/CONTROL

Comment: @bolov: vcpkg is a package manager, so I don't see how that's relevant. And - that "separate module" is artificial. No, I'm creating a stand-alone version of `stacktrace`.